# Torus link and knots

Tags: knot-theory

Hello :) i am reading about knot theory especially torus links :) i read "[Crossing number and Torus links](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/296368/crossing-number-and-torus-links)" and the answer isn't clear. Does there exist a solution without topology but with group theory (the cyclic group $C_p$) or other proofs (combinatorics)? It is very difficult from my point of view -.- ... Thank you for help :)

Comment: That question is about diagrams of knots.  So the shortest route to an answer involves arguing about four-valent graphs in the plane.